# FCM notification received but data part is not received

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am using firebase push notification service to send notification to ios device.
We are sending from server "data" and "notification" both notification is received but in data we are sending notification id and I am trying ko get that notification id send that id in api to show a notification on view But in my case i receiveing the notification but can't able to capture the notification id from data payload.

This is the payload we are sending from server.

```
data = new{                 
 title = pushMessage.Msgtype,                             
 description = pushMessage.Msgdesc,
 image = pushMessage.ImageURL,
 id = pushMessage.NotificationId },

notification = new  {
 body = pushMessage.Description,
 title = pushMessage.Title                            
}
```

This the code where I trying to capture the id.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        if let dict = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
      
            webServices.notificationId = dict["id"] as? Int
        } 
}
```

Comment: _can't able to capture the notification id from data payload_ - Please show your code.

Comment: Format should be like -

Comment: @vpoltave Please check I update My question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Payload should be like -

```
{
  aps={
    alert={
      body="Testing ppt 2";
      title="Online Training";
          };
      };
  "data"= {"id":"1"};
}
```